# How to properly use putAsync after promisify request module

Tags: node.js, request, http-post, promise, http-put

I searched here and there and ended up with no finding regarding putAsync method of promisified request by bluebird.

```
var request = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.putAsync({
    uri: buApiUrl,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: BU,
        workstations: formattedWorkStaions[BU]
    })
}).spread(function (response, body) {
    debugHelper.log(body);
}).catch(function (err) {
    debugHelper.error(err);
});
```

Above is the code snippet that is in my program. And it does not send put request. While using postAsync, if will send post request successfully.

Can anyone help explain why?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Where are you promisifying the put method or library that implements it?

Comment: @sdgluck, I already added promisification into the code snippet. Thank you for your response to my question. I think I have found out the reason why I cannot send put request. I will post my answer here soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the part where is wrong in the putAsync code snippet. I should use json not body as the key for the payload. And the payload does not need to be stringified.
Here is the new code snippet proven to work.

```js
var request = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.putAsync({
    uri: buApiUrl,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: {
        name: BU,
        workstations: formattedWorkStaions[BU]
    }
}).spread(function (response, body) {
    debugHelper.log(body);
}).catch(function (err) {
    debugHelper.error(err);
});
```

This is quite tricky and result in my second question. 
Why there is such a difference between post and put other than their method type?